# Hours and Average Hours Worked per Day, by Department

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get an estimate of how many hours people worked during a set period of time. I want to show this by department and by what area they were working in. Right now I have this:

```
SELECT M.MemberDepartmentID,T.TaskName,
    COUNT(DATEDIFF(HOUR, TT.StartTime, TT.EndTime)) 'Hours',
    AVG(DATEDIFF(HOUR, TT.StartTime, TT.EndTime)) Average
FROM Member.TaskTracking TT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Member.Task T
        ON TT.TaskID=T.TaskID
    JOIN dbo.tblMember M
        ON TT.MemberID=M.MemberID
WHERE M.FullTime=1
    AND M.EmployeeSalary=1
    AND (TT.StartTime >= '2013-10-01'
    AND TT.EndTime < '2013-11-01')
GROUP BY M.MemberDepartmentID,T.TaskName
ORDER BY M.MemberDepartmentID,T.TaskName
```

I don't know how to confirm if it's correct, but some are definitely showing averages of zero even if there were hours worked. And some averages are way higher than the hours worked. For instance, here are some of my results:

```
MemberDepartmentID  TaskName        Hours   Average
---------------------------------------------------
1                   Packing         25      0
1                   Picking         6       0
1                   PreScanning     38      7
4                   Picking         2       104
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Do start and end times always have values in the database?

Comment: Do you mean to be using count?  If you want to know how many hours I worked, I think you want to use a sum.  Count will just tell you how many occurrences there are, but they could all be zeros.

Comment: @StingyJack - Yes they do

Comment: Can you share some sample data in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlifddle.com) ?

Comment: Are there a lot of 0 entries? It could bring down the average.

Comment: ^ doesn't explain how there's an average of 104 hours between StartTime and EndTime when we are supposedly restricting the 2 times to lie on the same day :S

Comment: Can there be only one entry for any given task?  I think you may want to go back and look at your raw data.

Comment: @OGHaza - yeh, just thinking of the obvious reasons for 0 averages.

Comment: @OGHaza huh? The query shows a month worth of data, not a day.

Comment: @AaronBertrand bah, I'm having a bad SO day

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, it is important to note that `DATEDIFF(HOUR)` returns an integer, and it does not necessarily give a good reflection of how much time has actually passed. For example, these both yield `1`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '03:59', '04:01'); -- 2 minutes (0.033333 hours)

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '03:01', '04:59'); -- 118 minutes (1.966666 hours)
```

And these both yield 0:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '03:01', '03:59'); -- 58 minutes (0.966666 hours)

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '03:01', '03:02'); -- 1 minute (0.016666 hours)
```

Next, if you give SQL Server integers to divide, it's going to perform integer math. Meaning it will divide, but it will discard any remainder. This yields 0:

```
SELECT 3/4;
```

Even though really it's 0.75, and if it rounded up it should be 1. (Not that either of those results are particularly meaningful). Now, extend that to average.

```
DECLARE @d1 TABLE(a INT);

INSERT @d1 VALUES(3),(4);

SELECT AVG(a) FROM @d1;
```

This yields 3, not 3.5, which you would probably expect. For the same reasons as above.

Remembering that some of your tasks may have lasted up to 59 minutes, but would still yield an hour differential of 0, you could have, say, 4 tasks, three that lasted > 1 hour, and one that lasted < 1 hour. So your average calculation would essentially be:

```
SELECT (1+1+1+0)/4;
```

Which, as above, still yields 0.

If you want a meaningful average there, you should calculate the time spent more granularly than by hours. For example, you could perform the datediff in minutes:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '03:01', '04:59');
```

This yields 118. If you want to express that in hours, you could divide by 60.0 (the decimal is important) or multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '03:01', '04:59')/60.0;

SELECT 1.0*DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '03:01', '04:59')/60;
```

These both yield 1.966666. Much more meaningful to average such a result. So perhaps change your expression to:

```
Average = AVG(1.0*DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TT.StartTime, TT.EndTime)/60)
```

About the count, not sure what you're attempting to do there, but you may want to make similar adjustments to the calculation *and* probably consider using `SUM`. If you show some sample data and the results you expect, we can help more.

Also I recommend not escaping keyword aliases using `'single quotes'` - some forms of this syntax are deprecated, and it makes your alias look like a string literal. First, try not to use keywords or otherwise invalid identifiers as aliases; but if you must, escape them with `[square brackets]`.